# Downgrading Galaxy S6 from Nougat to Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Having problems rolling back to Android 6.

I put the phone into **Download Mode** (switching on with Home + Power + Volume down followed by Volume up)

Connect to Odin 3 v3.12 (and get **Added!!**)

Add in the md5 file to the AP section (which takes a few minutes)

When I hit Start it instantly fails with this stack trace....

```
Get PIT for mapping..

Firmware update start..

SingleDownload.

sboot.bin

Fail

Complete(Write) operation failed.

All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

On the S6 screen I get...

```
SW REV. CHECK FAIL. DEVICE: 5, BINARY: 4
```

[image: Fail Screenshot]

Comment: Most Samsung devices don't permit a downgrade since the bootloader is the latest with new OS and that prevents a downgrade

Comment: Could I ask why you want a downgrade?

Comment: Android 6 devices are on our list of supported devices and want them to run this OS rather than 7 for testing/support.

Comment: Please show us your **full** current firmware version, e.g. `G920FXXU5EQF1`. Refer to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180313/explain-dont-downgrade-warnings-when-flashing-stock-firmware/180315#180315) for a brief explanation on bootloader level and its effect on downgrading.

Comment: Unfortunately, all Nougat firmwares (and even some late Marshmallow ones) are already on bootloader level `5`, therefore downgrading through official means is impossible. It *might* be possible to load the device up with a custom recovery, then flash a custom ROM based on Marshmallow, but compatibility isn't guaranteed.

Comment: G920FXXU5EQAC is the current firmware.

Comment: @chris_elevate Then no go. The screen already tells you that by showing the red alert `Device: 5, Binary: 4`. As I said, if you don't mind warranty void, you can always try custom ROMs and see if they'd work.