# Change tablet OS

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, data-recovery, operating-system

I have an old android tablet. I want to install another OS on it. I am afraid of problems after installation. Is there a way to return to exact previous OS (android 5.1.1) if I have problems?

Tablet: Galaxy Tab A6

Comment: The article is written for Galaxy smartphones, but it may also work for Samsung tablets: https://www.xda-developers.com/download-stock-odin-firmware-samfirm/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain "Don't Downgrade!" warnings when flashing stock firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180313/explain-dont-downgrade-warnings-when-flashing-stock-firmware)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unofficial-n-14-1-sm-t285-lineageos-for-samsung-galaxy-tab-a-7-0-lte-gtexslte.4290531

Comment: @Robert Thank you!

Comment: @alecxs The link is useful. Thanks