# Downgrade from Android 11 to Android 10

Tags: android-10, android-11, downgrade

I upgraded my phone to Android 11 but now I have a lot of problems with it. The screenshot isn't working, and my phone is slow (on Android 10, it booted in < 30 seconds, but after the upgrade, it takes more than 2 minutes), sometimes when I open an app, it just shows a white screen and nothing is happening.

I want to switch back to Android 10 because I think it will be easier than fixing all these problems.

Is it possible? If it's possible, is there a way to downgrade through Android update or something like that, like when you want to update your OS, you just press download and install, and then it does everything automatically?

Comment: On regular phone (non-rooted botloader locked) Android version downgrade should not be possible.

Comment: Just do a clean install / recovery with a current firmware. Consult the phones manual or contact the manufacturer for the exact procedure.

Comment: Related regarding downgrade protection: [Explain "Don't Downgrade!" warnings when flashing stock firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180313/44325)

Comment: Although it is possible to downgrade Android 11 to 10, it could be risky and difficult. However, you didn't mention the phone model because different models have different processes. Similar problems have been discussed in [xda-forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-downgrade-android-11-to-10.4283809/) for Moto G phones.